# An online algorithm which counts window-restricted sign modifications

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-series

I am trying to think of an `O(n)` algorithm that does the following: given data (of length `n`) consisting of `-1`, `0` and `1` only, and a parameter `L`, return for each element in the data the number of "switches" from negative to positive or from positive to negative, in the last `L` elements.

For example, if `n=10` and `L=3`, the following input:

```
0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1
```

should return the following output:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2
```

Here's a naive Python code which does it in `O(n*L)` (I think):

```
import collections as col

def mods(data):
    d = col.deque(maxlen=3)
    for elm in data:
        d.append(elm)
        state = 0
        mods = 0
        for e in d:
            if state * e == -1:
                mods += 1
            if e:
                state = e
        yield mods
```

Comment: should [-1,0,1] also be counted?

Comment: Yes, that counts for 1. Edited in the post.